# Select second row in a join LINQ statement

Tags: c#, linq

I have a 1 to many relationship between Books and Authors dataset. How can I select the second author of the book (or null if there is only one author) using LINQ. I don't want to do a 'left join' because I only want to return books with authors. Some books do not have authors.

```
var books = from b in db.Books
             join a in db.Authors on b.Id equals a.BookId
            select new {
               Book = b,
               SecondAuthor = a ??? 
            }
```

Comment: How is that a 1 to many relationship? It sounds like you have many books with many authors. Unless each author can only be associated with 1 book, but that doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the first thing is that you should be using a group join, rather than a regular join, so that you get all of the authors as a collection, rather than flattening that into separate lines for each matching pair.  From that collection you can get the second item:

```
var books = from b in db.Books
            join a in db.Authors on b.Id equals a.BookId
            into authors
            select new {
               Book = b,
               SecondAuthor = authors.Skip(1).FirstOrDefault(),
            };
```

Comment: oh gosh.. i was striking my mind but coudl'nt remember the ``skip()``.:)

Comment: Thanks! This looks great. On my example above, if I left the code as is (removing the question marks obviously). Which author would be assigned to SecondAuthor. It seems to compile fine.